# how do i resolve the problem in this python program

Tags: python, list

```
l=[]
a=int(input('enter the number of list elements'))
for x in range(a):
    d=int(input('enter list element'))
    l.append(d)
print(l)
m=[]
n=len(l)
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(x+1,n+1):
        if l[x]==l[y]:
            continue
        else:
            m.append(l[x])

print(l)
```

output:

```
enter the number of list elements4
enter list element1
enter list element2
enter list element3
enter list element3
[1, 2, 3, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ELCOT/Desktop/hai/check1.py", line 11, in <module>
    if l[x]==l[y]:
IndexError: list index out of range
PS C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\hai>
```

Comment: You're trying to access `l[len(l)]`, which causes an index error. Why does your second `range` go up to `n+1`, not `n`?

Comment: What did you think `for y in range(x+1,n+1):` would do?

Answer (score 0):

```
         for y in range(x+1,n+1):
```

this line is causing the error that should be n i guess